# How do I set up NFS to respect user and group permissions?

Tags: debian, permissions, nfs

After creating an NFS share between two servers, **lb1** (nfs-client) and **data-server1** (nfs-kernel-server), users with permission on the NFS server do not have access on the NFS client.

### data-server1 configuration:

```
$ cat /etc/exports
/data  10.132.246.167(rw,no_subtree_check)
$ ls -la / | grep data
drwx--x--x  3 u1   users    4.0K Sep  6 03:55 data/
$ ls -la /data
drwxr-xr-x 3 u1       users    4.0K Sep  6 02:31 prod/
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep  6 02:31 keys/
$ awk -F: '$0=$1 " uid="$3 " gid="$4' /etc/passwd | grep 'root\|u1\|ftp\|www-data'
root uid=0 gid=0
www-data uid=33 gid=33
u1 uid=115 gid=100
ftp uid=999 gid=100
```

### lb1 configuration:

```
$ mount 10.132.245.223:/data /data
$ mount
10.132.245.223:/data on /data type nfs4 (rw,relatime,vers=4,rsize=131072,wsize=131072,namlen=255,hard,proto=tcp,port=0,timeo=600,retrans=2,sec=sys,clientaddr=10.132.246.167,minorversion=0,local_lock=none,addr=10.132.245.223)
$ sudo -u u1 ls -la / | grep data
drwx--x--x  3 u1   users    4.0K Sep  6 03:55 data/
$ sudo -u u1 ls -la /data
drwxr-xr-x 3 u1       users    4.0K Sep  6 02:31 prod/
drwxrwsr-x 2 www-data www-data 4.0K Sep  6 02:31 keys/    
$ awk -F: '$0=$1 " uid="$3 " gid="$4' /etc/passwd | grep 'root\|u1\|ftp\|www-data'
root uid=0 gid=0
www-data uid=33 gid=33
u1 uid=115 gid=100
ftp uid=999 gid=100
```

On the NFS server (ie, data-server1), root, u1, and ftp users have proper rwx permissions for the subdirectories of /data and can access the filesystem without any problems.  However, on the NFS client (ie, lb1), root and ftp get `permission denied` errors when trying to simply list directory contents of `/data` within the NFS share. User u1 on the other hand, works perfect.

This is one of my first usages of NFS

Comment: If a directory is `rwx--x--x`, only the owner can list it. Others can access files and subdirectories in it, subject to permissions on those files and subdirectories. In addition, user 0 on nfs clients is mapped to user 65534 on servers unless you have no_root_squash in the export line or do explicit userid mapping on the server. What kind of access do you want the users to have?

Comment: I should add that the reason no_root_squash isn't there by default is that historically, nfs clients were less trustworthy than the nfs server, with many clients sharing one server, and it's not good when a root user on the client accidentally does `rm -r` and cleans out the filesystem on the server.

Comment: @MarkPlotnick Thanks for the comments. I guess I was expecting the directory on the client to behave like it does on the server since all UID/GID match, but I can see now that the ```root``` differences were throwing me off and that it works as expected. Add your comments as an answer and I'll happily accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything looks as expected. Since `/data` is `rwx--x--x`, only the owner, `u1`, can list it. Others can access files and subdirectories in it, subject to permissions on those files and subdirectories.

In addition, userid 0 on NFS clients is mapped to userid 65534 (on some systems, -2) on servers unless you have no_root_squash in the export line (or, if running NFSv4, do explicit userid mapping on the server). Here are some details from the [exports(5) man page](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man5/exports.5.html):

> Very  often, it is not desirable that the root user on a client machine
> is also treated as root when accessing files on the NFS server. To this
> end,  uid  0  is  normally  mapped  to  a  different  id: the so-called
> anonymous  or  nobody  uid.  This  mode  of  operation  (called   `root
> squashing') is the default, and can be turned off with no_root_squash.
>
> By  default,  exportfs  chooses  a  uid  and  gid of 65534 for squashed
> access. These values can also be overridden by the anonuid and  anongid
> options.

Comment: Is this a security issue on a productive system?

Comment: @sneaky Can you please clarify? I'm not sure what you mean by "this".

Comment: OK, sorry, to clarify: Is it a good idea to use "no_root_squash" on a productive system exposed to the internet?

Comment: @sneaky I don't think it's a good idea to have no_root_squash unless you trust the root users on all of the server's NFS clients. And even with root_squash, the root users on NFSv2 and NFSv3 clients can still use `su` to become any other user and then have access to that user's files on the server. If it fits your use case, I'd suggest running NFSv4 with Kerberos, which supports per-user authentication and encryption of data as it passes through the network.